# Dual monitor support without X.org server possible?

Tags: console, multi-monitor, virtual-consoles

On a dual monitor setup, can you have both monitors displaying a shell without entering X (or any other graphical display server)?

And if it is not possible, why?

Comment: why do you tag /x11 and /xorg ?  If I understand correctly, you want to use dual monitor in console mode, right?

Comment: You are right. I've removed the tags.

Comment: do you consider `wayland` different to X? is the answer you seek to have a console interface instead of a graphical one? Would it be ok to have a graphical one with a fullscreen terminal emulator?

Comment: Are you talking about different virtual terminals per monitor, or the same virtual terminal for each monitor?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Is either option possible?

Comment: @itsok-dontworry I don't know. I'm just asking which option you have in mind. You are presumably aware that even if X is running, you can switch to a virtual terminal by Ctrl-Alt-F1 and so on, right? In this case, the monitors would show the same virtual terminal.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I'm interested in a console interface yes (I've modified my question, thank you).

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'd be happy to know of any option to control dual monitors without a graphical interface, either having two consoles open on each or one stretched out along both monitors. Switching into a virtual terminal after X has been started leaves me only with a single terminal on one of the monitors.

Comment: At least with Nvidia dual card support on my machine, I see one virtual terminal on each monitor. But perhaps you could expand on your use case? I'm not sure what the point of your question is.

Comment: @FaheemMitha That's interesting. The point of my question is curiosity: I'm just wondering why only one monitor is displaying the console and what controls that. I see no reason why a graphical environment would be necessary to have e.g. both monitors display the same terminal.

Comment: It is be possible, as both screens share the same framebuffer device, also check kernel parameters `video` and `console`, and have a look at `con2fb` code