# How to open different virtual consoles on different monitors?

Tags: linux, multi-monitor, virtual-consoles

I use a 2-display set-up (a laptop with a secondary 1280x1024 SXGA monitor attached to it) and whenever I switch to a virtual console (e.g. by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2) the secondary monitor switches to 1024x768 mode or something like that and just displays the top+left corner part of the primary monitor contents. Is it possible to configure the system to use the second monitor for a separate virtual console?

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of [Dual monitor support without X.org server possible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/266166/37849)